# Ping Pong Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, free-groups

In the book "Groups, Graphs and Trees" by John Meier, Lemma 3.10 is the Ping Pong Lemma. He uses different assumptions than for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_lemma). Namely, he states that

Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $X$ and $S$ be a generating set for $G$. Let $\mathscr{S}=S\cup S^{-1}$. For every $s\in\mathscr{S}$, $X_s$ shall be a subset of $X$ and $p\in X\setminus\bigcup_{s\in\mathscr{S}}X_s$. Now if

1. $s(p)\in X_s$ for every $s\in S$ and
2. $s(X_t)\subset X_s$ (proper subset) for every $s\ne t^{-1}$,

then $G$ is a free group with basis $S$.

I can prove the result if the first condition actually holds for every $s\in \mathscr{S}$ (so for inverses too), because then if $w=w_1^{n_1}...w_{k-1}^{n_{k-1}}w_k^{n_k}$ is freely reduced ($w_i\ne w_{i+1}$, $w_i\ne w_{i+1}^{-1}$) we have $w(p)\in w_1^{n_1}...w_{k-1}^{n_{k-1}}(X_{w_k})\subset ... \subset X_1$, so $w\ne e$ because otherwise $p\in\bigcup_{s\in\mathscr{S}}X_s$. This also works if the last letter of $w$ is not an inverse.

I thought, this might be a misprint in the book, however I also couldn't come up with a counter example.

Comment: It's hard to see the difference between $\mathcal{S}$ (caligraphic S) and $S$ (math italic $S$). So I switched the former to $\mathscr{S}$, which is more distinguishable.

Comment: I think, it was a typo.

Comment: If any of $w_1, \dots, w_k$ is in $S$ then we can conjugate $w$ so that the last letter is in $S$. Otherwise replace $w$ with $w^{-1}$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @SeanEberhard How can you conjugate $w$ in such a way?

Comment: E.g., $w_1^{n_1} \cdots w_{k-1}^{n_{k-1}} w_k^{n_k}$ conjugated by $w_1^{n_1}$ is $w_2^{n_1} \cdots w_k^{n_k} w_1^{n_1}$. Repeat as necessary.

Comment: @SeanEberhard So if $w_i\in S$, then I would conjugate $(w_i^{-n_i}...w_1^{-n_1})w(w_1^{n_1}...w_i^{n_i})=w_{i+1}^{n_{i+1}}...w_k^{n_k}w_1^{n_1}...w_i^{n_i}$ ? But then what if $w_1=w_k$ or $w_1=w_k^{-1}$ ?

Comment: You can assume from the outset that $w_1 \ne w_k^{-1}$: this is called being *cyclically reduced*. Otherwise, $w$ is conjugate to a strictly shorter word. Similarly you can arrange that $w_1 \ne w_k$ by doing an initial conjugation if necessary, unless $k=1$ and $w = w_1^{n_1}$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Oh, I understand. And if $w$ is conjugate to $awa^{-1}$ and we prove that $awa^{-1}=e$, then also $w=e$. Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in the comments section. Briefly, either $w$ or $w^{-1}$ may be conjugated so that its final letter is in $S$, and then the argument applies.